# Compile asm code string to binary in c++ runtime by fuction call

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I need some library that will allow me to do the following:

```
std::string asm_code_string=
"mov eax,edx
push eax";

char * binary_code=__Desired_Library__.convert(asm_code_string);
```

I hope I have conveyed the idea

Thank You.

Comment: From the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page: "Questions asking us to ***recommend** or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: If you find some library (using your favorite search engine) and have (some specific) trouble using it, then you are welcome back with a question about that.